# Keeping track of which buttons are selected in MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have dynamically generated buttons that are created based on a model I am creating in the VM. Each time i instantiate an instance of the model, it'll create a designated button for it and this button is what'll be changing throughout the application (it's background colour mainly).

Question is, when i didn't do it using MVVM (everything was in a UserControl), I had an observable collection of Model, and I also had an observable collection of Button, but I kind of wanted to not have to deal with 2 observable collections. I added a "IsSelected" bool to the Model but I don't know if that's the correct thing to do in MVVM terms, as I need to keep a list of buttons/Model instances that have been selected on the grid.

Below is my XAML which might help depict what on earth I'm talking about. I'll just post the itemcontrol

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="ObjItemControl" ItemsSource="{Binding ObjCompositeCollection}">
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                                        <Style>
                                            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding Row}"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Column}"/>
                                        </Style>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                             VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Name="objGrid" Grid.Row="1" 
                                             Width="{Binding MinWidth, ElementName=mainObjGrid}" 
                                             Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=mainObjGrid}"
                                             engine:GridHelper.RowCount="{Binding RowCount}"
                                             engine:GridHelper.ColumnCount="{Binding ColumnCount}" />
                                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsControl.Resources>
                                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type engine:ObjA}">
                                            <ToggleButton Content="{Binding Id}"
                                                    IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"
                                                    Height="{Binding ElementName=ObjItemControl, 
                                                Path=DataContext.ButtonHeightWidth}"
                                                    Width="{Binding ElementName=ObjItemControl, 
                                                Path=DataContext.ButtonHeightWidth}"
                                                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                            </ToggleButton>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type engine:GridLabeller}">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding HeaderName}" Style="{StaticResource GridHeaders}"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.Resources>
                                </ItemsControl>
```

My model.

```
public sealed class ObjA : GridConfiguration, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _Id;
    public string Id
    {
        get { return _Id; }
        set { _Id = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private bool isSelected = false;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return isSelected; }
        set { isSelected = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }
}
```

And how I am using this in the VM - this is in a loop

```
                    // Create obja
                    Obja obj = new Obja();
                    obj.Id = GridHelpers.GetRowName(i)
                    ObjSource.Add(obj);
```

The observable collection which is added to the composite container

```
    private ObservableCollection<ObjA> objSource = new ObservableCollection<ObjA>();
    public ObservableCollection<ObjA> ObjSource
    {
        get { return objSource; }
        set
        {
            objSource = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ObjSource));
        }
    }
```

So this is pretty much it, as I said, I want to be able to store the selected buttons in the viewmodel so i can change their background colour accordingly but not sure how to do this with MVVM.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your u can just iterate the collection and test the value of isselected. I still think it'd be better using a wrappanel or uniformgrid and positiin within the collection rather than a grid. To simplify building it I'd probably use a 2d array which you can therefore index on x and y. Iterate that into an observablecollection.

Comment: Dunno if you remember my previous questions but a uniform grid did not work out so well for the MVVM side of it... i couldn't have my textblocks on row 0 and column 0 and buttons filling the rest of the grid :(

Comment: but i could do the iterating of the collection and testing the isselected... that's a good call

Comment: You can datatemplate viewmodels out into different pieces of ui based on their datatype. Make it an observablecollection of object and add emptyvm for an empty cell, textvm for a textblock, buttonvm for button... Etc. Add a datatemplate for each in the itemscontrol resources.

Comment: Hmm... viewmodels as datatemplates? never heard of that..

Comment: No. Datatemplates as datatemplates. Associated with viewmodel type by datatype. http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Different_DataTemplates_for_different_types.aspx

Comment: Interesting... i'd have to read up more about this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MVVM, only the View is responsible for changing the way things are displayed. Hence, the background color of your buttons should be **handled in your View** and **not in your ViewModel**. A simple scenario is to use a `DataTrigger` in a `Style` to change the Background of your button depending on its `IsSelected` value:

```xml
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type engine:ObjA}">
    <ToggleButton Content="{Binding Id}"
        IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"
        Height="{Binding ElementName=ObjItemControl, Path=DataContext.ButtonHeightWidth}"
        Width="{Binding ElementName=ObjItemControl, Path=DataContext.ButtonHeightWidth}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        Click= "ToggleButton_Click"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ToggleButton.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ToggleButton.Style>
    </ToggleButton>
</DataTemplate>
```

You don't have to change anything in your ViewModel. For more complex behaviors, you should have a look at [Converters](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/WPFCustomValueConverter.aspx).

You can read [this article from MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/styling-and-templating) for more information on Styles.

Then in your code-behind you would have a click event handler from which you can retrieve the view model object:

```cs
private void ToggleButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ToggleButton tb = sender as ToggleButton;
    ObjA objA = tb.DataContext as ObjA;
    //From here you can perform operations on your view model.
}
```

This is a simplified example, in general using the code-behind is not considered good practice and you should have a look at the `ICommand` interface for more MVVM-like construction.

Comment: Hey Corentin Pane, what about storing the selected button part? Not quite sure how i can do this

Comment: Why do you want to store the selected ```ToggleButton``` object? All that matters to you is that its Background changes when it's effectively selected.

Comment: It's not only changing the background that I care about. Depending on buttons that are selected, I put them into certain groups (i.e. set a group ID in the ObjA model and give them a group colour which is used through a converter). I iterate over the list of selected buttons to determine if they are included in the canvas drag box that I have (it's a marquee tool)... so there are multiple reasons... but in my code i'm just doing a selectedbuttons.add, selectedbuttons.remove and a selectedbuttons.contains... and doing what i need to from there... maybe I don't need to if there are other ways...

Comment: for example, i store the previous button that was clicked so that I can click and drag and highlight each button as i drag along etc

Comment: mouse tracking as well when I'm dragging my mouse to create the marquee tool, that also confuses me in the sense of should it be in the view or the vm :(

Comment: You don't really care about the selected ToggleButton, you care about the viewmodel object whose IsSelected property is true. So to find out which view model is selected, just iterate over your collection of view models. Then add more bindings between your view and view model to perform more actions on the selected view model.

Comment: Where would I be iterating over? At the moment i've only got one view model (i'll branch out once i understand this all fully) but each togglebutton is related to a view of the model instance, so can i iterate over my observable collection in my view model where ObjSource is declared?

Comment: Yes you should iterate over objSource.

Comment: Thinking about it, ObjSource is a collection of ObjA, when a button is clicked, how can I check if that "button" is contained? I know we should be using the isselected, but how do we identify the ObjA to use since sender would be button? if that made sense

Comment: Is doing something like "ToggleButton tb = (ToggleButton)sender;" ok and then calling my "GetObjAFromToggleButton" function in the VM?

Comment: The VM should know nothing about any specific view element (like a ToggleButton). What you can do however is ```ToggleButton tb = (ToggleButton)sender;``` and then use ```tb.DataContext``` which should be a view model object. From here you can act on it.

Comment: `tb.DataContext` which should be a viewmodel object... do you mean it should be assigned to a viewmodel object?

Comment: Thank you for the awesome detailed answer! Appreciate it! :)