# Toggle button no longer changing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've been porting my usercontrol into a proper MVVM architecture, and it seems like my buttons are not switching their UI states as expected. My toggle button used to actually visually switch from on to off and vice versa when you clicked it, but now it doesn't do that, yet the command that switches the boolean that is bound to IsChecked works...

Here is the style in the resource dictionary for it:

```
<Style x:Key="ToggleButtonStyleForGroupSelector" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBackground}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBorder}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    <Border x:Name="on" Width="30" Height="25" Background="#FF063959">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="onText" Text="ON" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                   TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="White"/>
                    </Border>
                    <Border x:Name="off" Width="30" Height="25" Background="#FF063959">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="offText" Text="OFF" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                   TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="White"/>
                    </Border>
                </StackPanel>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="on" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SecondaryThemeColour}"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="onText" Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="off" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SecondaryThemeColour}"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="offText" Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The VM code for it:

```
    private bool isAddGroupToggleChecked = false;
    public bool IsAddGroupToggleChecked
    {
        get { return isAddGroupToggleChecked; }
        set
        {
            isAddGroupToggleChecked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsAddGroupToggleChecked));
        }
    }

    private void AddGroupToggle()
    {
        IsAddGroupToggleChecked = !IsAddGroupToggleChecked;
    }

    private ICommand addGroupToggleClickCommand;
    public ICommand AddGroupToggle_Click
    {
        get
        {
            if (addGroupToggleClickCommand == null)
            {
                addGroupToggleClickCommand = new RelayCommand(
                    param => AddGroupToggle()
                    //,
                    //param => (CurrentModel != null)
                );
            }
            return addGroupToggleClickCommand;
        }
    }
```

And the view XAML

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="4" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <ToggleButton x:Name="AddGroupToggle" Style="{StaticResource ToggleButtonStyleForGroupSelector}" Command="{Binding AddGroupToggle_Click}"
              IsThreeState="False" IsChecked="{Binding IsAddGroupToggleChecked}">
    </ToggleButton>
</StackPanel>
```

If anyone can spot the stupid thing I'm doing I'd appreciate it. Maybe it is datacontext related I don't know...

Comment: Havent spotted the error yet, but with `isAddGroupToggleChecked` and `nameof()`, you're one autocomplete away from raising a propertychanged event with the name of a private field (you aren't this time, I checked). The underscore prefix prevents that error. Anyway. Did you check the Output pane in VS for binding errors at runtime? And what's the command for?

Comment: Oh, wait: The binding is toggling the boolean property, and the command is then toggling it right back. Get rid of the command!

Comment: Wait what huh? What am I doing wrong? OH SHIZ! I've got a Command AND the IsChecked property! POO!

Comment: Thanks Ed :) don't worry about that one you glanced at, it's a bit of a lost cause where I was going with that. I fixed the Marquee tool one, but I'm curious about this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57943134/keeping-track-of-which-buttons-are-selected-in-mvvm/57943250#57943250. I have an observable collection of ObjA as you know, and I have a marquee tool, but what I don't know how to do nicely is get the X-Y positions of my ObjAs... They are technically buttons... but I don't want the VM to have to know about a list of buttons to check XY against...

Comment: Why the down vote??

Comment: Good question. I suspect because the question is just a mass of detail with one little thing that was just a mistake. It doesn’t add much to the sum of human knowledge. But you just can’t know. IMO it’s not a great question, but a legitimate one.

Comment: Thanks Ed... hey hum, such is life...

Comment: @usawpf Why would you want the x/y positions of your buttons? What's the goal with that? I doubt you need any x/y locations to do what you need to.

Comment: @EdPlunkett if you check out my drag box question, that's why I need to know their location so that I can determine if they are inside the rectangle or not

Comment: Yeah I'm doing it in the view code behind... But I was a bit annoyed that I had to iterate through the toggle buttons in the code behind and not have another way or binding or some such